# Оставить [firebase-android] или [android-firebase]?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть метки [firebase-android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-android) (24 вопроса) и [android-firebase](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-firebase) (1 вопрос).

По Android в целом принято метки называть по типу [android-fragment](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-fragment), где на первом месте `android`, т.к. это, всё-таки, первично.

Вопросы, связанные с Firebase под Android, выглядят как "Бла-бла-бла на Android, нужно бла-бла-бла с/из Firebase", то есть, Android первичен.

Я бы предложил сделать основной метку [android-firebase](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-firebase) и синонимизировать к ней [firebase-android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-android) (и объединить их), даже не смотря на то, что по этой метке вопросов меньше.

Comment: Думаю, тут возможен и другой вариант - первичным рассматривать таки `firebase`, т.к. наверняка есть вопросы по его использованию для яблока и яваСкрипта. Может ответы-голосовалки замутить и собрать мнение участников?

Comment: [tag:firebase] - общий. [tag:android-firebase] и [tag:ios-firebase], если вопрос касательно конкретной влатформы.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил ответы для голосования.

Comment: Напихал минусов на ответы)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метки объединены и синонимизированы. Теперь

> android-firebase -> firebase-android

Answer (score 3):

Основной меткой сделать [firebase-android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-android).

Answer (score -1):

Основной меткой сделать [android-firebase](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-firebase).

Answer (score -4):

Сделать основной [firebase](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase) и всё к ней синонимизировать.